# How to edit ng-zorro component css in nz-modal?

Tags: css, angular

This is my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dvf1z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Normally, I use

```
:host ::ng-deep nz-input-number {
  width: 100% !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep nz-date-picker span.ant-calendar-picker {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

will can change CSS as I want.

But **it is not working** with `<nz-modal>`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal HTML is part of your component. It means the view encapsulation is applied to it like it normally would.

So style it like you would style "normal" HTML.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dvf1z-rzp7f3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Note that for the second style, you have to use `::ng-deep` because this is a span inside a library component.

Comment: I got it.  Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you, you too ! If it helped you, be sure to mark your issue as resolved too !

Comment: I did it. I will accept your answer when enough time. tks again.